# Libvirt Qemu/KVM Fails on Guest Creation without any Specific Error Message

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to get started with Libvirt/Qemu/KVM on Debian 8.7.1. I've downloaded a Debian Stretch ISO to test it out. When I attempt to create a VM, the Debian installer initiates, configures root password, user, apt, and then fails at the 'Select and Install Software' step. There's no error message or anything. It literally says:

```
Installation Failed on this step: select and install software
```

And that's all it says. I checked `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/` and there's just a blank `mytest.log` file.

During the install, my terminal shows:

```
Starting install...
Allocating 'mytest.qcow2'                         | 4.0 GB     00:00     
Creating domain..
```

There's no error messages, even after it fails.

Here are the steps I took:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst virt-viewer virt-manager

adduser myuser kvm
adduser myuser libvirt

sudo usermod -a -G libvirt myuser
sudo usermod -a -G kvm myuser

virsh -c qemu:///system net-start default

virt-install --virt-type kvm --name stretch-amd64 --memory 512 --cdrom ~/Downloads/firmware-stretch-DI-rc3-amd64-netinst.iso --disk size=4
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this awesome tutorial](http://rabexc.org/posts/how-to-get-started-with-libvirt-on), and three days of trial and error, I managed to get this working with an Ubuntu 17.04 ISO, and also an alpha CoreOS ISO. A Debian 9 ISO, however, will not work. I will create a separate question for this issue because I believe it relates to virt-viewer.

The steps I took to get my original problem working are below. There were multiple issues, including permissions problems, disk size, and more. I purged, and reinstalled, everything from root, and then took the following steps (this is for an alpha CoreOS ISO):

```
$ su

# apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst virt-manager

# adduser jmnooor kvm
# adduser jmnooor libvirt

# sudo usermod -a -G libvirt myuser
# sudo usermod -a -G kvm myuser

$ mkdir ~/pools

$ virsh -c qemu:///system net-autostart default

$ virsh -c qemu:///system net-start default

$ virsh -c qemu:///system \
    pool-define-as mytest000 \
    dir --target ~/pools

$ virsh -c qemu:///system pool-autostart mytest000

$ virsh -c qemu:///system pool-start mytest000

$ virsh -c qemu:///system pool-list --all

$ cd ~/pools

$ sudo virt-install --virt-type kvm --name vm000 --memory=2048 --vcpus=2 --cpu=host --cdrom ~/pools/coreos_production_iso_image.iso --disk=pool=mytest000,size=10,format=qcow2 -w network=default --graphics=vnc
```